# CloudFormation "You are not authorized to perform this operation" creating SubnetRouteTableAssociation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

On a CloudFormation stack I get error on an operation of type [`AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnetroutetableassociation.html):

The exact error is:

```
Resource handler returned message: "You are not authorized to perform this operation.
(Service: Ec2, Status Code: 403, Request ID: XXXXXXXX, Extended Request ID: null)"
(RequestToken: XXXXXXXX, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

What bothers me is that I cannot see what API call has failed. Normally, I think it would have the operation name in parentheses so that it is easier to identify what goes on. Anyways, I'm taking a guess and **assuming** that it is the [`AssociateRouteTable`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AssociateRouteTable.html) permission that the user doesn't have. But user *has* this permission.

**Question: How can I identify the type of API Action that I need to grant the IAM user in question?**

#### What I've tried

I've tried to do (what I believe is) the same from the CLI:

```
aws ec2 associate-route-table \
   --subnet-id <subnet-id> \ 
   --route-table-id <route-table-id>
```

(obviously with the same values as my CloudFormation would be using). Doing it via the CLI works and correctly puts an event into the CloudTrail Event history of type `AssociateRouteTable`. But when I do it via CloudFormation I get the above error and no trace of any `AssociateRouteTable` event in the CloudTrail Event history.

Comment: Technically you can check CloudTrail to see what API operations were performed and failed.

Comment: @luk2302: Thanks, but as far as I can tell the CloudTrail Event History only has successful calls.

Comment: Nope, it also lists AccessDenied calls or calls that failed for validation or internal reasons.

Comment: @luk2302: Got it. But no event that matches anything remotely similar. I can see adjoining events, such as the given Subnet being created successfully one ms earlier. Pity that the UI doesn't support searching by `RequestId`.

Comment: Try using something like this https://github.com/iann0036/iamlive . Run the equivalent command in your cli and check the permissions required

Comment: But as luk said, there's definitely an entry in cloudtrail with the error message

Comment: @Paolo: This is CloudFormation. I think use of such a tool would require that I knew exactly which API calls a CloudFormation construct of `AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation` would emit.

Comment: I know, that's what I said. Try running it via cli https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-route-table.html

Comment: @Paolo: Have done it via the CLI now. Question has been updated.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. How are you deploying the template? Natively using cloudformation or are you using something like service catalog?

Comment: @Paolo: The CloudFormation template is being deployed via the CLI.   I think where your assumption are wrong is that there's no 1:1: relation between a construct in CloudFormation and API call on the other side. In fact in some cases CloudFormation may do several different API calls to satisfy a single construct. The $1000 question is to figure out what those are.

Comment: @peterh my assumption was that there was something missing from the permissions you were using to deploy the template, which was right it seems

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be very difficult to figure out. In the end I resorted to deploying the CloudFormation template from a user with `AdministratorAccess` policy. This worked, unsurprisingly, and provided me with "debug" information. From this action I could look into *CloudTrail Event history* and see that CloudFormation would execute *several* API calls in order to satisfy the `AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation` resource type. These were:

- `ec2:DescribeSubnets`
- `ec2:DescribeRouteTables`
- `ec2:AssociateRouteTable`

The last one on the above list would be no surprise. In my case the user was missing the permission to do `ec2:DescribeRouteTables` and the CloudFormation deploy would therefore fail with said error message. After adding this permission to user it now works.

This also explains why it worked when I executed the `aws ec2 associate-route-table` CLI command vs not worked from CloudFormation. The two are *not* (exactly) the same.

Go figure!

I sincerely doubt the majority of AWS nerds would go through same steps I've taken in order to figure this out, so I'm thinking there must be some documentation I've missed. Also, I still cannot explain why the failed API call does not show up in CloudTrail Event History. Alas, it works now, so I'm packing up.

Comment: No, in general there is no such documentation, maybe there is in your specific case. It is generally **extremely difficult** to write IAM policies that are as tightly scopes as possible, especially considering you need to also have the policies to update or delete the resources that were created (which is often forgotten).

Comment: @luk2302. Same experience. There's a lot of trial-and-error involved with pursuing a [POLP strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) in AWS. But I think the main problem with what I reported is that the error message has no information. The information about _which_ API call is failing, `DescribeRouteTables` in my case, isn't propagated to user. How on earth is an AWS customer supposed to figure this out?

Comment: When you say "provided me with debug information", where do you find that? Is it in the console? Or using the CLI? And how?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice:  By "debug" I meant that I could use _CloudTrail Event History_ (via the Console) to see exactly which API actions were being executed. I could then check these one-by-one to see if my POLP user had that API permission.